# converting names in a call to strings in r, c(a,b) -> c("a","b")

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want a function taking an unevaluated expression containing variable names into a new expression containing string for the variable names.

`c(a,b)`

should be converted to

`c("a","b")`

How can this be done?

Let me explain in more detail what I want to achieve.

```
my_tibble <-
  tibble(a=rep(c("a","b"),each=4),
              b=rep(rep(c("x","y"),each=2),2),
              x=seq_along(b)
  )
```

```
summary_groupwise <- function(data,group_var,var_to_summarise,result_var){
  data |>
    group_by({{group_var}}) |>
    summarise({{result_var}} := sum({{var_to_summarise}}))
}
```

This function works

```
summary_groupwise(my_tibble,a,x,group_sum)
```

Now I want to group by multiple variables

```
summary_groupwise_multiple <- function(data,group_vars,var_to_summarise,result_var){
  data |>
    group_by(across(all_of({{group_vars}}))) |>
    summarise({{result_var}} := sum({{var_to_summarise}}))
}
```

This works:

```
summary_groupwise_multiple(my_tibble,c("a","b"),x,group_sums)
```

To make `summary_groupwise_multiple` work, the names of the grouping variables have to be given as strings.

For consistency of the syntax, I would like the following call to work

```
summary_groupwise_multiple(my_tibble,c(a,b),x,group_sums)
```

How can is fiddle with the parameter `group_vars` so the call works without giving the names of the variables as strings.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example showing that anyone else can copy and paste into their session to see exactly what the input you have is and giving an example of such a function.

Answer (score 1):

If the expressions are passed as a vector i.e. with `c()`, an option is

```
f1 <- function(expr) {dput(sapply(as.list(substitute(expr))[-1], deparse))}
> f1(c(a, b))
c("a", "b")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun <- function(x)dput(as.character(substitute(x)[-1]))

fun(c(a, b, c))
c("a", "b", "c")
```